# mapping response of axios call to model

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am doing a simple axios call and getting few values. I want them to convert to a model. the problem is the server side uses different case [snakecase] and has underscores.. but in typescript model , it doesnt have anything.. 
How can i convert those response values to this model values?how to map them..

```
async getStudentstatus (): Promise<AxiosResponse<StudentStatus>> {
    return Axios.get(`url`)
  }
```

so the StudentStatus is like this

```
export interface StudentStatus {
    failedInAllExams: boolean,
    attendedAllExams: boolean,
    totalScore: number
}
```

but server side has value

```
{"failed_in_all_exams":true,"attended_all_exams":"true","totalScore":"290"}
```

I am looking manually do it ;not use a library since this is a one of a case

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/camelcase to convert data keys to camel case. I believe simple key conversion should cover 99% of possible cases.

Comment: this is one of a case.. so i am looking for some simpler [no etc package] solution..i can write it manually as well

Comment: In this case manual conversion could be the only answer here.

Comment: how to do it..thats my question

Comment: Just write plain mapping methods for every model you get from server. That will take some time, but you would be able to get good models which are bind to your application domain and would be someway protected from API change